# Using custom code to repopulate cache instead of Spring + Quartz integration

Tags: java, spring, caching, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

Reading about the configuration of implementing a scheduled refresh of a ehcache it seems that implementing a Quartz scheduler is required. I may be over simplifying but is below code not achieving same result :

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class MyCacheScheduler {

    public void repopulateCache(){

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
                Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture =
            scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Callable() {
                public Object call() throws Exception  {
                    myCache.clearCache();
                    myCache.populateCache();
                    return "";
                }
            },
            30,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        try {
            System.out.println("result = " + scheduledFuture.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Autowired
    private MyCacheManagerImpl myCache;
}
```

I'm just attempting to refresh the cache every X minutes. So when the cache TTL is exceeded multiple users are not all populating cache at same time. There is a risk this could still occur - if user accesses cache at exact time the TTL is exceeded and scheduled job has not re-populated cache. 
Configuring Quartz and integrating with Spring appears to be more work that using a Java ScheduledExecutorService but there could be potential issues using above code that I'm not aware of ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, if the way you invoke the cache refresh is correct, it should not matter how you perform the scheduling of that action. You could leave it as is (although you should also add a call shutdownNow followed by awaitTermination on scheduledExecutorService during server shutdown to stop it -e.g by calling it inside contextDestroyed method of a context listener) , use spring with quartz, or use plain spring's scheduling support with @Scheduled annotation since you use spring anyway (see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html for more details on spring scheduling).

So no, you don't need to use quartz if your question focuses on the scheduling part. If your question focuses on the way enchance works, sorry I have no knowledge of that.

Comment: I was not aware of Scheduled annotation , seems like this will suffice for clearing/repopulating cache. thanks, I'll investigate